# Comparando uma entrada de dados com uma lista, sem levar em consideração se a palavra começa ou não com letra maiúscula

Tags: python, lista, comparação

Gostaria de saber como faço para realizar essa comparação sem levar em conta se o mês digitado está em maiúsculo ou minúsculo, já que o programa só funciona se digito em minúsculo.

```
prompt = "Digite o mês de seu nascimento (digite exit para sair): "
active = True
meses = ['janeiro', 'fevereiro', 'março', 'abril', 'maio','junho', 'julho',
'agosto', 'outubro', 'novembro', 'dezembro']
while active:
    mensagem = input(prompt)
    if mensagem == "exit":
        active = False
    elif mensagem in meses:
       print("Você nasceu em %s" %(mensagem.title()))
    else:
        print("Este não é um mês válido, digite novamente.")
```

Antecipadamente agradeço pela atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça a comparação transformando também o que digitou para [letra minuscula](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_lower.htm):

```
prompt = "Digite o mês de seu nascimento (digite exit para sair): "
meses = ['janeiro', 'fevereiro', 'março', 'abril', 'maio','junho', 'julho',
'agosto', 'outubro', 'novembro', 'dezembro']
while True:
    mensagem = input(prompt).lower() # alterei aqui
    if mensagem == "exit":
       break
    elif mensagem in meses:
       print("Você nasceu em %s" %(mensagem.title()))
    else:
       print("Este não é um mês válido, digite novamente.")
```

Aproveitei para tirar o `active`, funciona perfeitamente sem ele, tem é de definir um break no loop `while`, que neste caso é quando a pessoa digita "exit"

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Sou iniciante em programação e sua ajuda foi de grande valia para mim.

Comment: Opa já implementei e funcionou perfeitamente. Vlw.

Comment: De nada @CarlosFerreira, ainda bem que resolveu